# WP8 Webbrowser element loads in debug mode, but not in release mode

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

In my WP8.0 app(say testAppA), I have a scenario in which clicking on a Push Notification received invokes a webbrowser element.
This invoking of webbrowser element happens in a library project which is added as reference to my application. Also in testAppA, there is only 1 xaml page(MainPage.xaml)which again contains a pivot element.

The scenario works perfectly fine when the app is running in debug mode. But while running the app in release mode, the webbrowser element is called, but it closes without loading the url onto it.

I am not able to identify the difference between the debug and release build scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this one, by adding the fast app resume capability to the testApp A. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj735579%28v=vs.105%29.aspx